# neo4j - how to restrict duplicate nodes with java

Tags: java, neo4j

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session;


public class adding {

    static Driver driver;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j","neo4j"));
        Session session = driver.session();
        session.run("CREATE (n:Person {username: 'bob'})");
        session.run("CREATE (n:Person {username: 'tom'})");
        session.run("CREATE (n:Person {username: 'bob'})"); // I don't want this ran

    }
}
```

Using neo4j with java how do I forbid the creation of the same node again?
For example, you can see in the above code that there are 2 bob properties.

How do I validate in java so that I know a bob node already exists.

`MATCH (n:Person {username: 'bob'}) RETURN n` in neo4j would show that there is already a bob node. so I'd just put an if condition over the third bob to be sure that no duplicate created. but not sure how to write that in java. And this current code is just a simplified version. My main code has user input rather than hard coded creations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [StatementResult](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementResult.html) is what you are looking for to run the Match query.

And you could do something like this.

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.StatementResult;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class adding {

    static Driver driver;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j","neo4j"));
        Session session = driver.session();

        List<String> userList = Arrays.asList("bob","tom","bob");
        userList.forEach(user->{
            StatementResult result = session.run( "MATCH (a:Person {username: '"+user+"'}) RETURN a");
            //Check if the node exists and create only if node doesn't exists
            if(!result.hasNext()){
                session.run("CREATE (n:Person {username: '"+user+"'})");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also, you may need to create [constraints](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/constraints/#constraints-create-unique-constraint) to avoid duplicates.

And if you like to get the result in a POJO class with Spring data then you need [@QueryResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/annotation/QueryResult.html) annotation to map the results to the POJO.